# Read and recv calls conflict

Tags: sockets, thread-safety, socket.io, vlc, recv

I am using vlc player for my lab setup. I am running the below code in a seperate thread in vlc.

do{

```
 ret = conManager->read(block);// basically calls the read system call 

 int rcvbuf=0;     /* Receive buffer size */
 socklen_t optlen; /* Option length */
 optlen = sizeof rcvbuf;
 int z = conManager->downloadQueue.front()->getConnection()->getsocket();
 if(z>0)
 {
 if (!(getsockopt(z,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf,&optlen) ))
     printf(" The socket buffer size is  %d \n", rcvbuf);
 }
 if(rcvbuf!=0)
 {
    t_block=block_Alloc(rcvbuf);
    rec = conManager->recv(t_block);//recv call with MSG_PEEK option set 
    printf("Received bytes : %d \n",rec);
    block_Release(t_block);
 }
```

if(ret>0)
    {

```
    block_t *bufBlock = block_Alloc(ret);
    memcpy(bufBlock->p_buffer, block->p_buffer, ret);
    bufBlock->i_length = block->i_length;
    buffer->put(bufBlock);

}
```

}
    while(ret && !buffer->getEOF());

When I start the video from the network , it displays two or three frames then it will give some error. Is my recv call modifying the data in the buffer? ..

```
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfa5a0] AVC: nal size -1870460177
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfa5a0] AVC: nal size -1870460177
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfa5a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfaa40] AVC: nal size -66001185
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfaa40] AVC: nal size -66001185
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfaa40] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f2060cfaee0] AVC: nal size -16048796
```

I checked on the error , but it says that the packet is truncated rather than at the end of the file . But if I run without recv . it works fine . Any idea on where exactly its going wrong .

Best 
Yash

Comment: What is the purpose of the recv() with MSG_PEEK, when you just throw the data away?

Comment: I want to know the amount of data present in the buffer , rather than removing  it from the buffer .

Comment: Is this UDP? How big of a buffer do you give to the `recv(2)`? You might want to add `MSG_TRUNC` to the flags to get the real datagram size.

Comment: @user980334 For what purpose? You aren't doing anything with it except printing it.